# Shortest way to check if 4 numbers are equal?

Tags: c

I have 4 numbers (int a, int b, int c, int d) that are equal to rand()%7. How can I discover if the numbers are equal to each other in the shortest way?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If (a==b && b==c && c==d)

Comment: Please don't use either `rand()` or (what perhaps is even worse) division by modulo (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator). As for your question, @Joachim is right. In such a small array the fastest way is to just compare each number with the following one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out if the numbers are equal to each other, you can do:

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d)
```

The condition above is supported by the transitive property of equality in mathematics in which it states that:

> If a = b and b = c, then a = c.

Given that property, we can state:

> If a = b, b = c, and c = d, then a = c, a = d, and b = d.

Source: [Mathwords](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single test:

```
int x = (1 << a) | (1 << b) | (1<< c) | (1<< d);
if ((x & (x >> 1)) == 0)
     printf("a, b, c and d are identical\n");
```

It works because all values are small, less than the number of bits in an `int`.   The test checks if `x` is a power of 2, which will only be true if all values of a, b, c and d are the same.

chux suggested a shorter solution:

```
if ((1 << a) == ((1 << b) | (1 << c) | (1 << d)))
    printf("identical\n");
```

It might not be shorter than the simple `(a == b && b == c && c == d)` in the number of instructions nor the computing time, depending on the specifics of your platform, compiler, options...

Here is a even simpler one that uses only one test and works for a larger range of values, for instance all positive `int` values:

```
if (((a - b) | (b - c) | (c - d)) == 0)
    printf("identical\n");
```

Comment: How about `if((1 << a) == ((1 << b) | (1<< c) | (1<< d)))) printf("identical\n");`?

Comment: Use as you like, it was inspired by your work and only a small variation on it.  Have doubts its better than `a==b && b==c && c==d`, but likely the best is compiler dependent.